# An alternative formulation of max flow problem

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, intuition, maxima-minima, network-flow

Let $G=(V,E,w)$ is a weighted graph where each edge $e$ has a non-negative weight $w_e$. We also have a distinguished source vertex $s$ and a sink vertex $t$. The maximum flow problem requires us to find a flow $f$ that routes as much flow as possible from source vertex $s$ to sink vertex $t$ while sending at most $w_$ units of flow over each edge $e$. In [this thesis](http://yintat.com/pdf/thesis.pdf?28744c) (page no 17), it is stated that maximum flow problem is equivalent to the following min-max problem

> $\min_{B^Tf=\chi}\max_e \frac{\lvert f_e\rvert}{w_e}$

Here $B$ is the usual edge-vertex incidence matrix and $\chi=1_s-1_t$. Then $B^Tf=\chi$ is the flow conservation property. I fail to understand this. Can someone please explain this? Thanks